# Deploy R shiny app on LAN: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'readyState' of null

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps, shinyjs, readystate

I've built a shiny web app that I would like to share with my colleagues.

I use for that `runApp(host = getOption("shiny.host", "10.161.112.8"))` where 10.161.112.8 is my host server IP adress.

The app works perfectly on my local server, but some remote client (not all of them !) directly get a greyed out screen (or after 1 sec maximum). When inspecting their web page source code, I get the following error:

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'readyState' of null
>     at ShinyApp.$sendMsg (shinyapp.js:288)
>     at ShinyApp.sendInput (shinyapp.js:140)
>     at InputBatchSender.$sendNow (input_rate.js:220)
> ```

I red [here](https://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/heroku-buildpack-r/issues/97) that it could be linked to web socket restriction. But I didn't found any solution that worked for me...

Doe's someone have any suggest? Any help would be great appreciable!